# Why stackoverflow used MVC over WebForms?

Tags: discussion, technology

Why stackoverflow uses ASP.NET MVC over ASP.NET webForms ? What advantages stackoverflow is getting by using MVC over WebForms ? If we needed a Seperation of Layers pattern , Why dont we add 3 Projects under our solution (for UI,for BL,for DB Access) and do it in typical Webforms ?

Answer (score 6):

Well MVC is testable, 
it asks for more disciplined programming, 
it lets you isolate sections of code

So if the guys can do MVC why should they take webforms and squeeze it so tight that it pretends to be MVC? I think the reasons above are enough to adopt MVC over webforms.

Oh and by the way, MVC is also the big hoohah that the geek-boys can flaunt right in the face of lesser mortals like you and me

*Count me out though, my new app is on MVC* :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you read past blog entries and/or listen to the podcast, you'll probably get a pretty good idea of what the SO Team likes about ASP.NET MVC.

But start with this little exercise... Look at a typical page on SO, and ask yourself: "What would WebForms add to this?"